Malfunctioning Keybinding with python prompt_toolkit package
I have this block of code in my python CLI app:
from prompt_toolkit.key_binding import KeyBindings
from prompt_toolkit.keys import Keys
from prompt_toolkit.application import run_in_terminal
    #Other irrelevent code
    binding = KeyBindings()
    @binding.add('c-l')
    def _(event):
        clear_screen()
    @binding.add('c-x')
    def _(event):
        def save():
            save = confirm("Wanna save the current state: ",suffix="[y/N]" )
            if save:
                print(to_do_list.save_current_state(json_data_file))
            else:
                print('Data not saved.')    
            event.app.exit()
        run_in_terminal(save)

The Ctrl+l keybinding works flawlessly, yet the Ctrl+X one doesn't.
Any help would be much appreciated.
I searched and went through the documentation, yet it wasn't much help.
I tried this fix provided by Claude AI:
from prompt_toolkit.application import get_app

@binding.add('c-x')
def _(event):
    app = get_app()
    
    def save():
        save_confirmed = confirm("Do you want to save the current state? ", suffix="[y/N] ")
        if save_confirmed:
            print(to_do_list.save_current_state(json_data_file))
        else:
            print('Data not saved.')
        app.exit()

    app.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(save)

But it didn't work.
